# Prove H = {a ∈ G | aga^-1 =g} ≤ G

Tags: group-theory

Prove that if G is a group, g∈G is a fixed element and H = {a∈G | aga^-1=g}, then H≤G.

Trying to study for my final and I missed this question on the first test (just marked wrong with no feedback). I'm completely stuck on showing that H is closed. I have no issue showing that the identity is in H since that's trivial. I think I'm okay with the inverse too its really just closure that is stumping me.

Comment: $(ab)g(ab)^{-1}$ is just $a(bgb^{-1})a^{-1}$...

Comment: *smacks face with hand*


thank you!